# Actionscript 3.0 Hyperlink Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created buttons that are essentially just hyperlinks to twitch.tv they work perfectly fine when I am previewing the UI via ctrl+enter within flash but when I export them to a swf when I click them nothing seems to happen... I am not sure if this is because of something I am doing when exporting them? But here is the code I have used

```
twitch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.twitch.tv"), "_self");
}
```

I have tried to global security settings panel with a tutorial I found but It wouldn't allow me to link my desktop through linking the location of files, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Navigate `Publish Settings` in Flash and select the `Access network only` from `Local playback security` option Menu. As shown in the image below.

[image: Publish settings]